# Identity Server 4 behind Load balancer giving unauthorized exception

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have setup Identity server 4 for one of my project using .net core as web api and angular as front-end technology. I have two servers (SRV1 and SRV2) where i hosted Identity server and they are under load balancer.

If I stop the one of the identity hosted server and do authentication, it works perfectly fine either or. But when I enabled both the server and generate token from first call that does not authenticate on another server.

To confirm it, I shut off one server (i.e. SRV1) and made authentication call to another server (ie SRV2) through load balancer and it returned me valid Token. when i used this generated token to access protected resources of SRV2, it works perfectly fine. after I used same token to get SRV1 protected resources, it throws unauthorized error.

Appreciate quick help.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure that the signing tokens and the [Data Protection keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/introduction?view=aspnetcore-3.1) are the same between the two servers. If you don't define them, they will be automatically created on each server (not the same) and that results in tokens/cookies from one server is not accepted by the other one.

Do see [this](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/crypto.html?highlight=material) article as well.